# How to pass python string to javascript as string in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a python string which is javascript code and I want to pass this string to javascript as string too.

My idea is to pass python string to javascript string and then use **eval()** function in javascript to turn that string to actual code and execute it.

```py
def login(request):
    success = '''
      window.location = '{% url 'home' %}';
      # some other codes
    '''
    return render(request, "app/login.html", {'success': success})
```

```js
var code = "{{success}}"
console.log(code) // return Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I have also tried pass the string as json like this

```py
def login(request):
    success = '''
      window.location = '{% url 'home' %}';
      # some other codes
    '''
    success = json.dumps(success)
    return render(request, "app/login.html", {'success': success})
```

```js
var code = JSON.parse("{{success|safe}}");
console.log(code) //return Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Last thing that I have tried is

```py
def login(request):
    success = '''
      window.location = '{% url 'home' %}';
      # some other codes
    '''
    return render(request, "app/login.html", {'success': success})
```

```js
<h3 id="success_id" hidden>{{success}}</h3>

<script>

var code = $("#success_id").text();
console.log(code) //return window.location = "{% url 'home' %}"

// if i do this
var code = "window.location = '{% url 'home' %}'";
console.log(code) // return window.location = /app/home/ 
// I want it to return the url like /app/home
</script>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) can be used to render the string and parse the template tags, specifically the `url` tag

Comment: did you check what you get in HTML after rendering? Why do you use `{% url 'home' %}` in `login()` ? It is code which you should use in `login.html` but not to insert it as argument because it may not understand it . In `login()` you could use normal string formatting or `f-string`  and function `url()` to create code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in essence what you want to do is using Django to pass data to js?

That has to to do with Django creating a Json Response which the JavaScript will then make a request , in essence you are working with some API.

your view code where you wrote the render function won't need that anymore...

Something like

```
JsonResponse({'success':success})
```

will be needed , after importing the JsonResponse from 'django.http'

Then at the js file, you will have to use Ajax to call that url with it's required method to get the data needed.

in your script tag , you will then need something like this

```
const xhr= new XMLHttpRequest ()
xhr.open('django_url', 'method')
xhr.onload = function () {
      const msg = xhr.response.success
}
xhr.send()
```

If you are familiar with fetch or axios you can as well use any library of your choice.

the django_url refers to the url that connects that view
the method refers to the http_method, either a 'GET' or 'POST' (most commonly used) .